# Json Web Token JWT

Tags: jwt

I'm trying to implement authentication by use of JSON Web Tokens (JWT).I searched a lot in google and GitHub but found nothing useful. Is there any pre-built web services on JWT(json web token) or public API's which can be used for testing purposes?

Comment: Which framework are you using? There are a lot of librairies which can handle JWT, client-side like server-side. For example, you can browse [auth0's github account](https://github.com/auth0?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=jwt).

Comment: you can see it from https://github.com/brijeshmavani/JWTWebAPI

Answer (score 2):

your question was quite vague in regards to what exactly you want to use JWT For and With so please have a read on how to correctly ask questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

I will however say that the following guide can perhaps help you on your way to implement JWT into your own system. It is a guide for Node.JS which explains step-by-step what you're doing and what your code is doing.

[Node.js API with JWT authentication](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens#getting-started)

This will allow you to quickly set up your own server and API to test on.
There is however a lot of information out there, you should be able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can found something practice on the internet. But I have some examples for use JWT.

Basically, you can have I class that has two methods: one method to generate the Toke, and another method to verify a token passed as parameter:

```
public class JwtToken {
private static final Key secret = MacProvider.generateKey(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);
    private static final byte[] secretBytes = secret.getEncoded();
    private static final String base64SecretBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretBytes);

    public static String generateToken(Login login) {
        Date now = new Date();
        Date exp = new Date();

        String token = Jwts.builder()
            .setId(login.getCpf())
            .setIssuedAt(now)
            .setNotBefore(now)
            .setExpiration(exp)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, base64SecretBytes)
            .compact();

        return token;
    }

    public static boolean verifyToken(String token) {
        try {
            Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(base64SecretBytes).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You need authentication by using of JSON web token you can use this [seed](https://github.com/imuble/Node-Passport-Mongoose-JWT-Seed).
This seed has a register and login function already implemented using passport-local strategy.

You need to just develop your client-side UI.